# Need to encrypt data key using Customer Managed Key in Azure Key Vault from CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-keyvault

I need to generate some encrypted data key using Azure Cli.
Earlier i worked with AWS , and to encrypt data , we use something like below:

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id 1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab --plaintext fileb://ExamplePlaintextFile --output text --query CiphertextBlob | base64 --decode > ExampleEncryptedFile
```

I googled out but not getting similar way for Azure Key Vault

Comment: Oh man, I'm looking for exactly the same stuff - but there is no answer. I was getting closer with one step - using az cli, you can get the private part of the key, and with openssl you can use for encryption.

Comment: We're you any lucky?  I need exactly the same